# Named query-use <query> and <sql-query>

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, named-query

I have read Named query. We can use **< query>** and **< sql-query>** in mapping file for named query. I cant understand the difference between **< query>** tag and **< sql-query>** tag. When we have to use **< query>** tag and when we have to use **< sql-query>** tag.

e.g.

```
<query name="findOneEmp">
    <![CDATA[from Employee e where e.empId= :empID]]>
</query>
```

and

```
<sql-query name="findEmpNativeSQL">
   <return alias="employee" class="com.common.Employee"/>
   <![CDATA[select * from employee e where e.empId = :empID]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: query mean hql and sql query means native sql :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query tag are meant for HQL queries, and Sql-query is meant for declaring the native sql queries.